# Redirect in Master Page Before Content Page Load

Tags: asp.net, events, redirect, master-pages

I have code in my ASP.NET master Page_Init event page that checks if a user is authorized to be on the content page, and if not redirects them to the login page. This code works fine as far as the check itself.
However, I have discovered that the content Page_Load event still fires after the above redirect.
This is causing a problem on pages that assume the user is logged in and certain variables are set.

This is the master page code (simplified)

```
    Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
...
            If Access_Level > User_Level_ID Then
                Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx", False)
            End If

    End Sub
```

The above test works fine, and the redirect line is executed, but doesn't take effect before the code below is fired and executes.

This is the content page code

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim Rec_IDs As New List(Of String)
    Rec_IDs = Session("Rec_IDs")
    lblCount.Text = String.Format("You have {0} records in your cart", CType(Rec_IDs.Count, String)) 'this gives an error if Session("Rec_IDs") is null
End Sub
```

I realize I can put code in each of my content pages to check if a user is logged in / authorized, but I wanted to control it all from one location if possible.

Am I doing something wrong? I've read so many pages that say the master page is the place to do the check.

Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
...
            If Access_Level > User_Level_ID Then
                Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx", True)
            End If

    End Sub
```

Using Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx", True) will terminate the current page processing & redirect to desired page.

Though it is recommended to use "Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx", False)" but this will not terminate page execution. It will redirect after current page processing end.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much. I marked your answer as accepted because you beat the other guy by 2 minutes. :-)

Answer (score 3):

It does so because the 2nd argument in your Response.Redirect is set to `false` - which means you're not ending the execution of the rest of the page.

If you set it to `true`, page execution ends (prevents the Page_Load of the content page/s from firing. **EDIT**: as well as any other subsequent Master page events for that matter)

```
Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx", True)
```

Check what it does to all your pages though....e.g. your `login.aspx` page *shouldn't* have the same master page the way the code is written above...

Comment: Works great, thank you very much. 
Btw, login does have the same master page, but code I didn't include above allows anyone to access it, and a few other pages.
Thanks for the heads up though.